# Extract dataframe from lm model object

Tags: r, lm

Simple question for which I haven't been able to find the answer.

I'm looking for a function that extracts the name of the data frame used as input from an `lm` model object.

So for example, if I run

`model <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)`

I want a function like

`data.name(model)`

that produces

`mtcars`

I've looked [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/extracting-information-from-objects-using-names/) and [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/model.frame.html) but they don't seem to be giving me what I'm looking for. For example, unless I'm using `model.frame()` wrong, it just gives me the data frame with the terms used in the model, not the original input data frame.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`model$call$data` gives you `mtcars` (an unevaluated symbol); `deparse(model$call$data)` gives you `"mtcars"` (a string). `eval(model$call$data)` gives you back the original data object, if it is available in the current environment.